# xQuery LIKE-operator?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, xquery

Is there any way to perform a LIKE operation with XQuery in the same way as with SQL?

I wan't to construct some "startswith", "endswith" and "contains"-expressions.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
for $x in /user where $x/firstname LIKE '%xxx' return $x
for $x in /user where $x/middlename LIKE 'xxx%' return $x 
for $x in /user where $x/lastname LIKE '%xxx%' return $x
```

Is there any way to achieve this in XQuery?

EDIT:

Got the answer to the question above. New problem:

Would there be any way to do this the opposite way around? I would like to run those queries with the sql equivalent NOT LIKE operator. Is this possible? It has to be in an FLWOR-expression

EDIT2:

Solved the problem. You can run fn:not(starts-with('123', '1')) and it returns false.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the constraint "it has to be in a FLWOR expression". What's wrong with the simpler formulation `/user[matches(firstname, '.*xxx')]`? Simple path expressions are often more concise than FLWOR expressions.

Comment: This is a useful question, which you seemed to have answered yourself, but not provided the output. Can you post your answers here please ?
Were you able to use the syntax of the LIKE comparator string or did you have to translate it to an xQuery specific comparison string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 (as standardized by the W3C) have regular expression support with the `matches` function http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches:

```
/user[matches(firstname, 'xxx$')]
```

And of course there are functions like `starts-with` and `contains` (both in XPath 1.0/2.0), and `ends-with` (only in XPath 2.0) that might suffice.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: +1 Good answer. Edited because last sentence might be confusing.

Comment: XPath 1.0 equivalent of `ends-with` XPath 2.0 function: `substring($string, string-length($string) - string-length($pattern) + 1) = $pattern`

Comment: Would there be any way to do this the opposite way around? I would like to run those queries with the sql equivalent NOT LIKE operator. Is this possible? It has to be in an FLWOR-expression

Comment: @JorgenR. inverse with `not()` boolean function.